# How can I check if a URL parameter exists using .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to check if a URL parameter and a specific value exists using `.htaccess`. I need to block (return `403`) access if parameter is not present or does not match the value.

Basically, if the user goes to `example.com/login?key=d35`, they should be allowed to see the page and follow the login workflow.

If the `key` parameter does not exist or the `key` parameter does not match `d35`, then return a `403` status.

**UPDATE:**

The question is quite specific as I need to use `.htaccess` for a specific scenario where I have a specific set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this blocking rule as your top rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)key=d35(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: I'll test it and get back to you.